# What is the best way to manage Express timouts in 2019?

Tags: node.js, express, timeout, connect-timeout

Running into a situation where requests are crashing on Heroku before as Node process exits, leaving that Node process orphaned — and delivering an ugly Heroku error message.

What I think needs happens is: Express needs a timeout set, and once reached, stops any process in flight (and handles the timeout in a graceful way — sending an error message to user).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-timeout

I'm looking at `connect-timeout` and it seems a little awkward to sandwich in a `haltOnTimedout` after every middleware. Is there some other (better) way to manage timeouts in Express or this the best way?

Comment: How does a nodejs process get orphaned when it exits?  Whether it exits normally or crashes, the process is stopped, not orphaned.  I don't understand what problem you think you have?

Comment: If you've a long job, maybe should you run it as a background, and alert the frontend user with a websocket tools as socket.io or ws to inform him, no ?

Comment: Its not Node that exits, its Heroku. Leaving the Node process orphaned.